# How does @autowired annotation works for a private field?

Tags: java, spring

How does `@Autowired` annotation work for a private field without a getter and a setter?
How can spring access a private field?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17531269/1297272

Comment: it's `@automagic` because spring uses reflection for it's dependency wiring mechanisms.

Comment: Disagree that this is a duplicate, since those questions are purely about reflection. This question is asking essentailly why does the spring framework use reflection in this mechanism

Comment: It can autowire  using constructor and also using the type specifier.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It works with [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html) you can find an example of how to set public fields. But setting private fields does not make much of a [difference](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/private-fields-and-methods.html)

The only difference with a private field is that you will need to set the setAccessible before you are able to read/write to the field. Further, this method can throw a SecurityException.
[Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible-java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject:A-boolean-)

Comment: The only difference with a private field is that you will need to set the `setAccessible` before you are able to read/write to the field. Further, this method can throw a `SecurityException`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible-java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject:A-boolean-

Comment: right, forgot about the SecurityException, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component
public class A(){}

@Component
public class B(){
@Autowired
private A a;
}
```

Spring create beans mentioned as @Component. here bean A will be created first and since B is dependent on A, then injection of A to B is done. there's no need for any setters. just @Component is required. Spring uses CGLib for creation of beans using reflection.

Answer (score -1):

**Three types of dependency injection**

There are at least three ways an object can receive a reference to an external module:

**constructor injection:** the dependencies are provided through a class constructor.

**setter injection:** the client exposes a setter method that the injector uses to inject the dependency.

**interface injection:** the dependency provides an injector method that will inject the dependency into any client passed to it. Clients must implement an interface that exposes a setter method that accepts the dependency.